# How to receive input from python socket server in android studio?

Tags: python, java, android, sockets

I have a python socket server that receives a string from an Android app and should return the same string in uppercase. The app can send the string and I receive it in the server but how could I receive the returned string in the Android studio?

**Here is my python code:**

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
with conn:
    print(f"Connected by {addr}")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data.upper())
```

**Here is my sending message function**

```
Socket s;
PrintWriter pw;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
    String message = voids[0];

    byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
    boolean end = false;
    String dataString = "";

    try {
        s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", Integer.parseInt("65432"));
        //sending data
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.write(message);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        //////////
        //receiving data


        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Use the inputstream of the socket i would say.

Comment: I added the inputstream and when ever I use it it prints this error W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:930)  but the socket was never closed and the server is always running

Comment: forgot to mention @blackapps

Comment: pw.close() closes the socket too. Post your code!